# How to use a regular expression to remove lines without a word?

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

I am using textmate to edit a file. I would like to remove all the lines not containing a word. Here is an example.

```
apple ipad
hp touch pad
samsung galaxy tab
motorola xoom
```

How can i remove all the line not containing the word "pad", and get this result, using Regular Expression??

```
apple ipad
hp touch pad
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you want to *remove* or *keep* all lines with the word "pad"? Does "pad" have to be at the end of the line, or anywhere?

Comment: "pad" is in anywhere. i want to keep the line with "pad", and remove all the other lines. Kizu's answer solved my problem. Thanks for your help RoToRa. :)

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for that.  It just helped a bunch.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Replace `^(?!.*pad.*).+$` with empty string

Comment: Would you please explain about this regex? @kizu

Comment: @natansun `(?!)` is a “negative lookahead” which is zero-width by itself, but matches only when it won't find the content inside of it. So there we're looking for just anything inside a line — `.+`, then looking if it doesn't contain `pad` prefixed with any other symbols — `(?!.*pad.*)`, and if this expression would be found, we can replace it with an empty string that would basically remove the line.

Comment: I tweaked it a little and used `^(?!.*(10039|10038|10037|10036).*).+$\n` to replace lines that don't have any of the words I want and also remove the line break in the process.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about doing this kind of thing using regular expressions but you could easily use grep to do this.

For example, if the file *textfile* contains this:

```
apple ipad
hp touch pad
samsung galaxy tab
motorola xoom
```

Open Terminal, and run this command:

```
grep pad textfile
```

It'll output this:

```
apple ipad
hp touch pad
```

If you want to save the output to a file you can do something like this:

```
grep pad textfile > filteredfile
```

Comment: Thanks daxnitro. This is a good solution. But kizu's answer is better as I can get the result right inside textmate. But thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

This expression will select lines that contain the word pad:
`^.*pad.*$`

The `^` character indicates the start of a line, the `$` character indicates the end, and `.*` allows for any number of characters surrounding the word.

This may be too wide-ranged for your purpose in its current state - more specific information is needed.

Comment: Yup. This can get all the lines with "pad". But I want to remove the lines without this word. I didn't know how to do that before. Thanks for answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for providing an explanation of characters in the expression.